# I get exception after pressing click() for "FindElementByID"

Tags: c#, winappdriver

I get exception after pressing click() for "FindElemebtByID". I get this exception:

> Error CS1061  'ReadOnlyCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Click' and no accessible extension method 'Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ReadOnlyCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My code is:

```
var EQ = DesktopSession.FindElementByName(@"C:\Users");
var EQWindowHandle = EQ.GetAttribute("NativeWindowHandle");

EQWindowHandle = (int.Parse(EQWindowHandle)).ToString("x");    
EQWindowHandle = "0x" + EQWindowHandle;

DesiredCapabilities EQcapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
EQcapabilities.SetCapability("appTopLevelWindow", EQWindowHandle);

var EQSession = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), EQcapabilities);

EQSession.FindElementsById("7.8556.12446183").Click();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`FindElementsById` returns a `ReadOnlyCollection`.

You need to pick the relevant item from the collection before attempting to call click.

This will take the first item returned and then call click on it.

```
var elements = EQSession.FindElementsById("7.8556.12446183");

var element = elements.FirstOrDefault();

if (null != element)
    element.click();
```

Alternatively, if you're always sure that either, there is only one element with the Id `7.8556.12446183`, or that you want to use the first element with that Id (there really shouldn't be more than one), then you could use `FindElementById` instead as below.

```
var element = EQSession.FindElementById("7.8556.12446183");

if (null != element)
    element.click();
```